# In Pandas_ta supertrend give me wrong result in lower timeframe how to convert this pine code to python?

Tags: python, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

In pandas_ta give correct result compare to Trading View if Time Frame is higher but for smaller timeframe it gives wrong value, if anyone help to convert this code to python??

````
indicator("Pine Supertrend")

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(3, 10)
plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up direction", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down direction", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

// The same on Pine
pine_supertrend(factor, atrPeriod) =>
    src = hl2
    atr = ta.atr(atrPeriod)
    upperBand = src + factor * atr
    lowerBand = src - factor * atr
    prevLowerBand = nz(lowerBand[1])
    prevUpperBand = nz(upperBand[1])

    lowerBand := lowerBand > prevLowerBand or close[1] < prevLowerBand ? lowerBand : prevLowerBand
    upperBand := upperBand < prevUpperBand or close[1] > prevUpperBand ? upperBand : prevUpperBand
    int direction = na
    float superTrend = na
    prevSuperTrend = superTrend[1]
    if na(atr[1])
        direction := 1
    else if prevSuperTrend == prevUpperBand
        direction := close > upperBand ? -1 : 1
    else
        direction := close < lowerBand ? 1 : -1
    superTrend := direction == -1 ? lowerBand : upperBand
    [superTrend, direction]

[pineSupertrend, pineDirection] = pine_supertrend(3, 10)
plot(pineDirection < 0 ? pineSupertrend : na, "Up direction", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(pineDirection < 0? na : pineSupertrend, "Down direction", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)```
````

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have also same problem